# svn: E155004: ..(path of resource).. is already locked

Tags: svn

I'm getting an error when trying to commit a change to a repository. I'm sure that my resources (classes) are not locked but it still gives me the error:

```
Some resources were not updated.
svn: E155004: Working copy 'D:\svnworkspace\crm\weblayer\com\lmkr\crm\web\model\dashboard' locked
svn: E155004: 'D:\svnworkspace\crm' is already locked
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Update and [clean](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.cleanup.html) your working copy.

```
svn update
svn cleanup
```

---

If nothing else works, save your changes as a patch (**TortoiseSVN** → **Create patch...** or `svn diff > changes.diff`), and check out the repository anew. You can then apply the patch to the new working copy (**TortoiseSVN** → **Apply patch...** or `svn patch changes.diff`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got it working already, svn service was not running #whatashame

Comment: Is this `To remove the locks and recursively clean up the working copy, use svn update.` from the link you give a typo? Shouldn't that `svn update' say `svn cleanup`. I was doing `svn update` when it moaned about the locks, so `svn update` can't be the solution, or even part of it.

Comment: @BillWoodger Try any combination of `svn update` and `svn cleanup`. If that doesn't work, delete and recreate the working copy. Create a patch before you do, if you want to keep your uncommitted changes.

Comment: Thanks, it worked yesterday (forgot to upvote, so did now). I just can't understand why it says `svn update` at that point in the docs, when the description is what `svn cleanup` does, as far as I can tell :-)

Answer (score 23):

**Solution:**

**Step1:** Have to remove “lock” file which present under “.svn” hidden file.

**Step2:** In case if there is no “lock” file then you would see “we.db” you have to open this database and need to delete content alone from the following tables

**– lock**

**– wc_lock**

**Step3:** Clean your project

**Step4:** Try to commit now.

**Step5:** Done.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked for me. Needed to modify the SQLite database using "http://sqlitebrowser.org/" on my mac.

Comment: For me the file was wc.db. Cleaning the lock and wc_lock worked!

Comment: Just putting commands incase - [C:\sw\sqlite>sqlite3.exe C:\workspace\project1\.svn\wc.db "select from wc_lock"] and then execute this [C:\sw\sqlite>sqlite3.exe C:\workspace\project1\.svn\wc.db "delete from wc_lock"]

Answer (score 13):

For me worked, in Eclipse:

**Team -> Cleanup**

Answer (score 6):

This happens while switching. Before starting **close the eclipse.**

These are the steps I follow to solve and works for me.

- Eclipse Version:Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
- SQLLite version: DB.Browser.for.SQLite-3.11.2-win64

Steps:

1. Download -  https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/ I downloaded zip version.
2. Extract the downloaded zip.
3. Open "DB Browser for SQLite"
4. Locate your .svn folder - C:\Workspace-Eorder\myNCR_Release_5.0.0.0.svn\
5. Open the "wc" file.
6. Go to SQL Query browser:
7. select from wc_lock;   --- if lock you get some rows.
8. delete from wc_lock
9. Close and save the changes.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Still if it doesn't work, just lock all the files and unlock. 
Now clean up again, It will work.

svn update
svn cleanup

Answer (score 3):

//Inside the folder,

svn  cleanup

svn  update

//If are viewing any conflicts,

svn  revert  --depth  infinity  conflicted_filename

svn  update  conflicted_filename

svn  update

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem

The problem is that with Subversion 1.7 this doesn't work anymore. The good news is there is a better way to do this - and what it appears I should have been doing this all along. All you need is:

```
svn cleanup
```

found the solution [here](http://www.rabblemedia.net/removing-an-svn-lock.html)

Answer (score 2):

Inside the folder

**TortoiseSVN -> Clean up...**

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem and we solved it as follows : 
we tried a "revert from SVN" from another folder than the one we faced the issue,
and suddenly we were able to perform commit,revert etc from the folder that had the issue.
It seems that it firstly needs to commit a change from another dir.

BR

Answer (score 1):

Just cleanup. Happened in JetBrains PhpStorm

Answer (score 1):

1. Downlaod and copy sqlite.exe to `.svn`'s parent directory
2. Open shell in this directory
3. Query to find locks in corresponding tables => in wc_lock* table (the table name is something like this)
4. Delete the locked items in above table by sqlite query

just this steps helped me to resolve:

```
svn: E155004: Working copy 'resourceAddress' locked
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it's worked with **svn cleanup** in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. I have solved it in the next steps.
In the command line you have to type just

1. "svn cleanup"--> run ,than
2. "svn update" --> run

and you have to check it ,that your App. is working without any failures or not, and
if everything is ok, you can commit your changes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked making a merge (WinMerge in Windows, Meld in Linux) between locked project and a new project checkout. After that, I continued working on the new project checkout, and the lock problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when my (Windows) computer hung with 100% hard disk usage after I ran **SVN Update** from **Eclipse**. After waiting for some time, I had to do a hard reset on my computer.
After starting it up again and trying to run SVN Update from Eclipse again, I got the error

> E155004 [project name] is already locked

Tried one of the suggestions of running **SVN Cleanup** from **Eclipse**. The same error appeared.
I then used **TortoiseSVN** instead to run "Clean up" with the following options: **Clean up working copy status**, **Break write locks**

The clean up ran successfully. After which I was able to do SVN Update from Eclipse.